# hazelcast distributed id generation

Tags: sequence, distributed, hazelcast

Hazelcast has inbuilt distributed id generator as mentioned here http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/idgenerator.html. The challenge is whenever cache server restart the sequence is lost and restart from zero. As a solution they try to provide an init function which can start id from a specific int. What is the best way to use it to have a continuous id generation no collision which will persist even after server restart and give best performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can persist the ID and set it to the last value after node restarts. Depending on your needs of a continuous ID you might want to look into another external (my) project https://github.com/noctarius/snowcast which works differently.

Comment: is this taking care of the risk of id reset when hazelcast server restart. Is there any configuration/ coding which is needed to done to comply that.

Comment: Since the upper block of the ID is a timestamp there is no ID reset on restarts. It means you have no really continuous ID but you have unique IDs that support ordering. If you read the documentation of snowcast, you'll find out how it works.

For the IdGenerator in Hazelcast, well if you reload the ID from the database obviously it works too.